# Eclipse for C/C++ header file not found

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I got a C project with a Makefile.
I import the project to eclipse for C/C++(Neon.3 Release (4.6.3))

But when build the project, eclipse cannot find some of the header files.

[image]

I have installed the pcap lib in my system.

> apt-get install libpcap-dev

but, I can use make command to compile the C project.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem in eclipse?

Comment: `pcap` isn't the only one with an error, though. `stdlib.h` shouldn't have any problems, but it is also marked

Comment: do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: This usually happens when CDT's built-in compiler settings discovery fails. What compiler are you using to compile your source files? Is the compiler executable in the PATH, as seen by Eclipse? Is the Built-in Compiler Settings provider enabled in Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> Providers?

Answer (score 0):

For *CDT projects*, you can define include paths and preprocessor symbols for the parser.

If Autodiscovery is enabled, after a build finishes, any discovered paths and symbols will be displayed in the Discovered Paths section.

*You can also define the properties on a per project basis in the C/C++ Projects or Navigator views.*

To add include paths and symbols:

1. To set properties for your project, right-click your CDT project and select **Properties**. Alternatively, to set properties for a specific source file in your project, right-click a source file within your make project and select **Properties**.
2. Expand **C/C++ General** and select **Paths and Symbols**.
3. Click **Add** to define new element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc).
4. Click **Edit** to change selected element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc).
5. Click **Delete** to remove selected element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc).
6. Click **Export** to make selected element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc) exported.
7. Click **Unexport** to remove selected element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc) from export list.
8. Click **Move up** and **Move down** to set elements (Include Paths, Library paths etc) order.